# Error running multiple instances of sphinx (searchd) on the same box

Tags: php, mediawiki, sphinxsearch

I have a MediaWiki server that hosts 4 instances of MediaWiki, and figure I should have a separate instance of **sphinx** search running for each.  I did this by creating separate sphinx.conf files for each, and configuring them to run on **separate ports**

The setup of sphinx was pretty straightforward, and allowed me to specify a **custom port** for each instance, all the way up until **SphinxSearch.php**, which appears to re-define the port using **wgSphinxSearch_port**. I commented out this line, and the search appears to work fine for all instances.

The problem I have is that php throws an error at the top of the page:

> Warning: assert() [function.assert]: Assertion failed in /var/lib/mediawiki-1.11.0/extensions/SphinxSearch/sphinxapi.php on line 251

I know I can turn **display_errors** off in **php.ini**, but that's not a real solution.

Has anyone else run into this problem?  Am I the only one running multiple instances of *searchd*?

**Why is this error being thrown, and how can I fix it?**

Answer (score 2):

That line is asserting that the specified port is an integer. My guess is that the assert fails since wgSphinxSearch_port is now undefined.

I don't know why you'd need multiple searchd instances. What prevents you from using a single instance and different indices for each wiki db?